# Merge/Append in R – how to add variables without generating more rows

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets – data A and data B. Data A contains 30.000 observations while data B has 10.000 observations. Both datasets have 156 countries – noted with their ISO–number.

I want to add some of the variables in data B to data A (let's say the variable Y*). However, I face problems when merging these two datasets.

Below you can see the samples of the datasets

Data A

```
Country     ISO year    X
A           1   1990    0
A           1   1991    0
A           1   1992    0
A           1   1993    0
A           1   1994    1
B           2   1990    0
B           2   1991    0
B           2   1992    0
B           2   1993    0
B           2   1994    1
```

Data B

```
Country        ISO  year    Y*
    A           1   1990    1
    A           1   1994    0
    B           2   1990    1
    B           2   1992    0
```

So I am interested in getting the variable Y* into my data A. To be more precise, I want to add it by country and year.

Below you see the code that I use to add the Y* variable. I have used this code many times and it works perfectly. I cannot figure out why it doesn't work in this case.

```
variables <- c("Country", "year", "Y*")

newdata <- merge(DataA, DataB[,variables], by=c("Country","Year"), all.x=TRUE)
```

When I run this code, I get "newdata" with the variable Y* but with 5 times more rows than Data A.

**Question:** Is there any relatively simple and efficient ways of doing this properly? Is there something with the structure of dataset B that creates more rows? In any ways, I am grateful for all kinds of suggestions that could solve this problem.

This is the outcome I want to get:

```
Country        ISO  year    X   Y*  
    A           1   1990    0   1
    A           1   1991    0   0
    A           1   1992    0   0
    A           1   1993    0   0
    A           1   1994    1   0
    B           2   1990    0   1
    B           2   1991    0   0
    B           2   1992    0   0
    B           2   1993    0   0
    B           2   1994    1   0
```

Comment: Um, try `by=c("Country","ISO","year")` if your data actually looks like that.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. my data looks similar to the examples above. 
Even with your suggestion I get more rows, unfortunately.

Comment: Or try dply package. `left_join(dataA dataB, by=c("Country","year")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the merge. Make sure to readjust the values of the Y* variable

z <- merge(DataA,DataB, by = intersect(names(DataA), names(DataB)), all = TRUE)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it partially worked but still 4 or 6 rows more. Much better than before of course. I just need to figure out where these 15-20 rows comes from..any idea? I tried all.x=T and it gave me 9 extra rows..

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you mean by "readjust the values of the Y*"?

Comment: Hi. When I used the samples you provided, the observations with no corresponding values had NAs in the new column. Maybe it was a quirk of the data you provided. My code worked with this tiny bit. Let me know if you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
require(dplyr)
left_join(DataA,DataB %>% select(Country,year,Y*), by=c("Country"="Country","year"="year"))
```